# How to disable matMenuTrigger when there are no mat menu items rendered in mat menu

Tags: angular, material-design

I want to disable the mat menu trigger when no mat-menu-items are rendered because of ngIf conditions in the mat-menu

```
<button
    mat-button
    [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"
    [disabled]="????"
  > Trigger
</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <button
      mat-menu-item
      *ngIf="foo1"
    >
      <span>Button</span>
    </button>
    <button
      mat-menu-item
      *ngIf="foo2"
      <span>Button 2</span>
    </button>
</mat-menu>
```

There is a items property for matMenu which is unfortunately deprecated

Comment: Use a JSON array and check with dynamic mat-menu.

Answer (score -1):

you should enveloppe the matmenu with another ngif which check's the array length size so it will disable the display and remove it from the dom